Android App Update Reduces Supported Devices on Google Play
I recently uploaded the *.aab for an update to one of my apps, but the Google Play Developer Console gave the following warning:
This release will cause a significant drop in the number of devices your apps supports on the following form factors:
In the details, is says:
Doesn't support required ABI (2,248 devices)
arm64-v8a
x86_64

This update was created using .NET for Android 9.0, while the previous releases were created using Xamarin.Android, but they both have a minimum API of 21. I also have the Platform Target set to Any CPU. What am I forgetting or doing that could be reducing the number of supported devices? Thanks!

@Nathan Sokaski
You would need something like the following in your proj file.
<RuntimeIdentifiers Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">android-arm64;android-arm</RuntimeIdentifiers>

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog for a complete list of RuntimeIdentifiers for Android.
The example above covers all modern Android devices. I think the minimum API now is 25 for net9.0-android35. I'm not sure because I don't go that low.

That sounds like it is probably correct, but I have a couple of questions. First, in the link you give, it lists the following RIDs:
android-arm64
android-arm
android-x64
android-x86
This includes the ones you give, along with a couple others, but none of them look like the ones listed in the message I am receiving. Will these RIDs take care of the ones in my message? Second, the message talks about ABIs, while your link talks about RIDs. Are these the same thing? Either way, thank you for your help, it will definitely give me a good starting point!

I think AndroidSupportedAbis became RuntimeIdentifiers with the change to .Net. Google definition vs Microsoft definition. At the same time, redefinition of the Rid names. As I said in my email, upload another build (using the above) to Play Console and recheck the number of supported devices.
